# Redirection of http to https not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I want to redirect my subdomain to https. My .htaccess file contains the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https: //%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It's redirecting to https but my chrome browser giving an error

> This webpage has a redirect loop The webpage at https: 
>   //sub.domain.com/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your
>   cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the
>   problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a
>   problem with your computer. Learn more about this problem. Error code:
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

please help me

Comment: Does your .htaccess file really have a space between `https:` and `//`?  If so, there's your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using following configuration for redirecting all requests for `http://somedomain` to `https://somedomain`:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [redirect=301]`